# Console disappearing instantly

Tags: c

I'm new to using C in visual studio. I have this code and I can't figure out why it's acting the way it is. I put the getchar() to stop the console window from disappearing. It still disappears though unless I have the second getchar(). Why does it do this and why does a second stop it?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int nums[10];
    int number;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%i", &number);

    printf("%i", number);

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i; i < 10; i++){
        nums[i] = rand() % 50;
        printf("nums[%d] = %d\n", i, *(nums + i));
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first `getchar()` reads the newline that's left in the input stream after `scanf()` (which read in the integer you entered, but not the newline after it).  The second `getchar()` waits for another character to read.

Comment: This is not the main problem, but you should include `stdlib.h` to use `srand()` and `rand()`, and include `time.h` to use `time()`.

Comment: Also, the first `i` in `for` does nothing. It does neither help or harm.

Comment: Well that is tricky. I have't used C in years and it's a different way of thinking to me. This is just for fun and to reintroduce myself to the language. Thanks for pointing that out! Never would of noticed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `getchar()` should read `'\n'` which is not read by `scanf`, so it will return immediately.

The second `getchar()` doesn't have anything to read, so it will wait for input.

Comment: I'd use `system("PAUSE");` which has the additional advantage of not working in Linux.

Comment: This answer makes perfect sense. Sorry if this question was asked before, seems like a common problem. Googled for a while but wasn't exactly sure what to google as I didn't know the problem.